# Executing build xml from the remote machine

Tags: shell, ant

Suppose on my remote linux machine(i.e B) one folder is there in which build.xml is placed and I have to call the deploy target from that xml. I have to execute this build xml from another linux machine(i.e A) .

This activity has to be run in automated way such that it will not ask for the password in between from the user ,if required I can hard code that password.

Can anyone please help me with the small snippet of shell script or with the ant task so that I can do this activity.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Simply run your remote build via ssh using keys, configure => userhome/.ssh/authorized_keys .. so no password needed

Comment: Install a build server like Jenkins. It's designed to solve this problem, by managing remote builds. Very simply add the B server as a Jenkins slave and you'll have a management console for your builds.